# Lookup a PHP function at php.net and show the definition in Vim status bar

Tags: php, vim, dictionary, wget

How can I make a mapping that will lookup a function definition on the php.net webpage and display the result in the Vim status bar?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Indeed I did, because the answer below is mine! :D I wrote both the question and the answer at the same time.

Comment: Ah! Though it's not forbidden on Stack Overflow to answer one's own question, you're addressing your own, narrow requirement here only. I would have preferred to post this mini-plugin on vim.org or GitHub, which also enables better feedback and maintenance.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Yeah, I guess one should generalize the code snippet into a tutorial on how you can fetch data from a web page using a simple mapping. Hm.

Comment: And for that I would suggest the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of steps are required to do this:

1. Replace `_` with `-` in the function name to fit URL naming convention. **Edit**: Not needed if you call `php.net/function_name`.
2. Call wget with Vim `system()` function and store the result in a variable or register
3. Normalize the output from wget with hxnormalize
4. Select the specific div with hxselect
5. Remove all tags, like `<span>`, using sed and a regex
6. Echo the result if it's found, otherwise echo an error message

This is the mapping that will do all this (should be edited to fit a single line)

```
vnoremap <leader>php :<c-u>let fn_name = substitute(@*, "_", "-", "g")<cr>
:let @a=system('wget -q -O - "php.net/manual/en/function.' . fn_name .  '.php" 
\| hxnormalize -l 240 -x 
\| hxselect ".dc-title" -c 
\| sed -e "s/<[^>]*>//g"')<cr>
: if @a != "" 
\| echom @a 
\| else 
\| echom "Could not find function " . fn_name
\| endif<cr>
```

You will now be able to highlight a word with `ve` and then print `<leader>php` to get the function definition.

OBS: `+x11` (shown in `vim --version`) is required for the `@*` register to work correctly.

Comment: Just so you know `php.net/function_name` et al. will redirect to the normalised URL if the function exists, you shouldn't need to reformat the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depending on having the php.net available you can use Vim's php omni-complete, phpcomplete, instead to provide the signatures.

Add the following to your `~/.vim/after/php.vim` file:

```
function! s:quick_man(word)
  if !exists('g:php_builtin_functions')
    call phpcomplete#LoadData()
  endif
  let word = a:word . '('
  echo word . get(g:php_builtin_functions, word, ' can not be found')
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> K :call <SID>quick_man(expand('<cword>'))<cr>
```

Note: Use [shawncplus's phpcomplete](https://github.com/shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim) fork then you will have even more signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Never got omni-complete to work.

Comment: The omni-complete that comes stock with Vim (7+) will do. You just need to make sure you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `~/.vimrc` file. This doesn't mean that the PHP omni-complete is amazing, but it is better than nothing